# Inline Function Arguments Passing

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, const-reference

Is there a need *performance*-wise for *inline* functions to pass its arguments by *const reference* like

```
foo(const T & a, const T &b)
```

compared to by value

```
foo(T a, T b)
```

if I don't change the values of a and b in the function? Does C++11 change recommend anything specific here?

Comment: A value is a value and a reference is a reference. Passing a const reference when meaning instead passing a value is a mistake that can bite back badly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705593/int-vs-const-int/4705871#4705871

Comment: @6502: That's a great example of a case where using a reference makes the logic more complicated (`v.push_back(v[0])` is legal, because the standard library must include that extra logic).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nice to see this request has been added to the standard. Where is it stated?

Comment: @6502: If the reference is valid when `push_back` is called, it's the responsibility of the standard library to do the right thing with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry but I don't agree. When calling a function passing a reference if the referenced object doesn't live long enough for the duration of the function it's a caller problem (the callee has no control on it). AFAIK the standard doesn't say that the copy operation must be done before the deallocation: if an implementation wants to do so ok, but a valid C++ compiler can make daemons fly off my nose still remaining compliant. By the way things are even more complex now with C++0x... can reallocation use move constructor? If so just delaying destruction of old storage is not enough...

Comment: @6502: This is something that the library implementer has control over and the caller doesn't.  The caller is responsible to not delete the passed object during the function (for example from a callback or another thread), and the callee is responsible to not delete the passed object until it's no longer needed.

Comment: Anyway, it's already been proved that `v.push_back(v[0])` is safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210688/what-is-the-right-way-to-avoid-aliasing-e-g-when-adding-an-element-of-a-conta/6212163#6212163

Comment: @BenVoigt: Also after discussing this in the chat Alf P. Steinbach brought another important point (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1594676#1594676). If you pass a function a reference to an object that doesn't live long enough then you're already in UB land and the C++ implementation is not required to behave in any prescribed way. `v[0]` is not going to live long enough in case of reallocation and therefore the implementation is free to do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: @6502: But you're passing a reference which IS valid.  So you're not in UB-land.  If the caller caused the reference to become invalid, that'd be on the caller.  But if the standard library invalidates a reference, it needs to not use the reference afterwards.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm in UB land because I'm passing a reference to an object that will not live long enough because it's valid only until there is a reallocation. So it's my fault (the caller) to pass it to a function that may need to do a reallocation, possibly before using it. In general the called function has no way to control how long will live an object received by reference, so it's a caller responsibility to ensure that it will live long enough. Imagine that I pass `push_back` a reference to an object that is destroyed when `::operator new` is called... would still be a library fault?

Comment: @6502: But there's clearly a difference between an object destroyed by `push_back` itself, and one destroyed by code that only the caller has control over.

Comment: (Postscript to above comments -- I took 6502's side [in another discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18788780/103167) and no one agreed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass by value can only elide the copy-constructor call if the argument is a temporary.

Passing primitive types by const reference will have no cost when the function is inlined.  But passing a complex lvalue by value will impose a potentially expensive copy constructor call.  So prefer to pass by const reference (if aliasing is not a problem).

Comment: In addition to aliasing problems there are lifetime problems.

Comment: @6502: On return values, definitely.  For parameters, lifetime issues can occur, but they are very rare.  And I would consider them a subset of aliasing issues anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt `Passing primitive types by const reference will have no cost when the function is inlined.` Do you mean, "will have no benefit in term of cost"? Can you confirm if there's anything to gain passing a `const int&` or a `const int` when the function is inlined?

Comment: @Antonio: No, I meant what I said.  In general there are significant costs to passing by `const` reference: the callee has to access a pointer in addition to the actual data, which means twice the memory accesses.  The callee also has to worry about aliasing, which inhibits several optimizations.  When the function is inlined, the compiler can determine whether aliasing is actually possible and often can do those optimizations and access the data directly instead of through an extra pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically the ones without reference might be copied in memory as there is the possibility that your inline function might be modifying them (even if it actually doesn't).

In many cases the compiler is smart enough to pick out that kind of thing but it will depend on the compiler and the optimization settings. Also if your function call on any non-const member functions in the class variables then your compiler will have to be smart enough to check if they are modifying anything as well.

By using a const reference you can basically give it a fairly clear indication.

EDIT: I just to a look at the machine code for a simple [test program](http://pastebin.com/XL9Ku7zm) compiled with GCC 4.6 in ddd. The generated code seemed identical so it does seem to be optimized out. It's still good practice though for other compilers and if nothing else give a clear indication of the code's intent. It's also possible there are more complex situations that the compiler can't optimize though.

Also the [llvm online dissembler demo](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) shows identical bitcode is generated there too. If you turn off optimization it is slightly longer without the const reference.
* 1964 bytes - No const reference (and no other consts on functions/paramaters)
* 1960 bytes - Just no const reference but other consts.
* 1856 bytes - With consts and const reference.

Comment: If the inline function passes a and b to another function, it may not be possible to optimize out the copy. For example, if the inline function calls non-inline function `bar(a)` the compiler must copy because bar might do `if (&a == &special) ...` and the original caller may have passed `special`.

Comment: Try again, with a non-POD type.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the optimizer if a member function is declared `const` or not. Const-correctness is invisible for the optimizer and is  something that has been designed only to help programmers (by giving compile-time errors if you violate the const declarations), not the optimizer.

Comment: @6502: const-correctness does affect optimization in some cases, although I agree than constness of a member function is not one of them.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What can affect optimization are const **values**. Constness of a reference (as in `const X &`) or of a pointer (as in `const X *`) is never an help for the optimizer because it's a declaration that says nothing about the const-ness of the object being referenced or pointed to (those declaration only determine what operations are valid on the pointer/reference).

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference is faster than by value depending on data type.
However for inline functions the function body (and thus all references / passed in values) are added to the line of code they are used in anyway so technically there are no variables being passed around, only more lines of code in the same area.

reference http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson13.html

There is also a very helpful answer under the question [should-i-take-arguments-to-inline-functions-by-reference-or-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722257/should-i-take-arguments-to-inline-functions-by-reference-or-value)

- Example may have been misleading, removed -

Comment: This is entirely speculation.

Comment: Passing by reference is faster than by value **depending on the type**. Also code that uses a reference has additional requirements (for correctly handling aliasing) and may require an extra indirection not needed for native types passed by value.

Comment: Apologies, I got pass by pointer mixed with value for some strange reason, you are correct it is only faster for some data types. I also point you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722257/should-i-take-arguments-to-inline-functions-by-reference-or-value which supports my point